# How do I view .asp Images?

Tags: perl, image, windows-7, asp-classic

I am trying to download images from a site using Perl to download and save them with LWP::Simple.getstore.

Here's an example of the URL

http://www.aavinvc.com/_includes/blob.asp?Table=user&I=28&Width=100!&Height=100!

Turns out the files are completely empty that I am getting with LWP. I even tried cURL and same thing, completely empty. Would there be another way to get these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file really contains ASP, then you have to run it through an ASP engine.

If things worked properly, then the URL would return an image file with an appropriate content type. You've just saved it with a .asp extension.

The fix is simple: **Rename the file** (preferably by looking at the Content-Type header returned (trivial with LWP, but I think you'll have to move beyond `getstore`) and doing it in Perl.

Regarding the update:

I just tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use LWP::Simple;

LWP::Simple::getstore(q{http://www.aavinvc.com/_includes/blob.asp?Table=user&I=28&Width=100!&Height=100}, 'foo.jpeg');
```

… and it just worked. The file opened without a hitch in my default image viewer.

Comment: Well, I'm even trying this in Chrome. I'm going out to some site with the .asp URL, and it displays an image. I right-click save-image-as and the only option is a .asp file. I tried renaming it to .jpeg or .gif or anything else, but then it was corrupt.

Comment: If your browser won't let you rename the file (although I don't see how that is relevant since you are fetching it programatically) then save it and rename it afterwards.

Comment: If it was then corrupt then it wasn't a JPEG or a GIF. Look at the content type header and figure out what it actually is.

Comment: I am. I save the file as .asp, then rename it in windows and open it with an image editor, nothing.

Comment: As I said, look at the Content-Type. Find out what it actually is.

Comment: As for your update where you specify the URL: I follow it, Firefox tells me it is a JPEG in the title bar, I right click, I pick save, it offers to save it as *blog.asp.jpg*. It just works, without having to muck about at all.

Comment: Ah, I found one problem. LWP is returning an empty string and saving it. Same thing with cURL. Do you know of another way to fetch this with Perl?

Comment: Ok, that seems to work for me to. I'll try to figure the rest out from there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.asp is not an image format.

Here are two explanations:

1. The image are simple jpegs generated by .asp files, so just use them if they were .jpegs - just rename them;
2. You are actually downloading a page that says "LOL I trol U - we don't allow images to be downloaded with Simple.getstore.

Comment: I posted a URL I am trying to get. Is there any other way to do this then?